# AngularJS custom filter for highlight text

Tags: html, angularjs

I create a filter on a table. Here the code:

```html
<table id="tableText" class="table table-hover table-striped" ng-init="allNews()">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Ricerca testo" class="form-control" ng-model="inputText">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Titolo</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Disattivato</th>
    <th>Modifica</th>
    <th ng-if="!cancelDelete">Elimina</th>
    <th ng-if="cancelDelete">Annulla</th>
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="news in allNews | filter : inputText">
    <td>
      <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]"><span ng-bind-html="news | deleteTitle"></span></div>
      <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="news.title" /></div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]"><span ng-bind-html="news | deleteText"></span></div>
      <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="news.arg" /></div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]"><input type="checkbox" disabled ng-model="news.isDeleted"></div>
      <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="news.isDeleted"></div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]"><button id="modify" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="modify(news, $event)">Modifica</button></div>
      <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><button id="accept" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="update(news)">Accetta</button></div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div ng-hide="editingData[news.id]"><button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(news.id)">Cancella</button></div>
      <div ng-show="editingData[news.id]"><button id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="cancelModify()">Annulla</button></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The entry on the table is read from db:

```js
$scope.allNews = function () {
  var url = '/data_db.asmx/GetAllNews';
  var obj = {};
  $http.post(url, obj)
  .success(
    function (response) {
      if (response.Error) {
        console.log('Server error');
      }
      else {
        $scope.allNews = response.d;
      }
    })
  .error(
    function (response) {
      console.log('Unkwnow error.');
    });
}
```

I'd like to highlight the text that is search in the 1st row of the table. For now, i receive this error:

> angular.js:13920 Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: function ()

but the filter works.

Comment: can you add your filter codes?

Comment: Have no filter code! This is the "magic" D: I use `ng-model="inputText"` in the input search, and then filter on the ng-repeat with `filter : inputText`

Comment: You don't need a filter but directive or component. Filter uses for **filtering** not for DOM manipulation.

Comment: Also, you are using `allNews` for the array **and** the method. Change the name of the method. (`news in allNews` and `$scope.allNews = function () {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `$scope.allNews` is a `function`. When you use it in `ng-repeat` directive and the directive is evaluated for the first time, your angular will try to examine the `allNews` property of your `$scope` as an array.

When the function gets called the first time (which might never happen when angular first encouters the error), it woul overwrite the `allNews` property with the resulting array of your `$http` POST request.

Rename either the function or the property and bind your ng-repeat to the array it recieves (and maybe initialize it with an empty array until it is populated by the `$http` result).

Something like:

```
$scope.allNews = [];

$scope.getAllNews = function() {
var url = '/data_db.asmx/GetAllNews';
var obj = {};
  $http.post(url, obj)
  .success(
    function (response) {
      if (response.Error) {
        console.log('Server error');
      }
      else {
        $scope.allNews = response.d;
      }
    })
  .error(
    function (response) {
      console.log('Unkwnow error.');
    });
}
```

Alternatively try using ngResource, create a service and inject that into your controller. Then populate the array by accessing the service.